# python, removing parts of a list (and a bit more)

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, pygame

I'm making a music player for my raspberry pi. 
It is shoud remove '/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/'from the strings in my list.But i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Music Player(Alpha2.2).py", line 19, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(SongPath + Song[0])
error: Couldn't open ' Toto - Africa.mp3'
>>>
```

I think it is because of the space between ' and Toto but I don't know how to fix it. BTW here is the code:

```
import glob
Song1 = glob.glob('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/*.mp3')
Song2 = glob.glob('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/*.ogg')
Song = Song1 + Song2
Song = [s.strip('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/') for s in Song]
Song = [s.replace('/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/','') for s in Song]
SongPath = '/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/ 
print('Music Player(Alpha2.2)')
import pygame
from time import sleep
Song = sorted(Song)
CurrentSong = 0
State = 'Playing'
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(SongPath + Song[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play()
print("Songs:")
for i in range(0, len(Song)):
    print(i+1, Song[i])
print('\nStarted auto play on:\n' + Song[CurrentSong])
```

Comment: can you verify that the path exists? print(os.path.exists(Song[0])

Comment: If you do not remove the full path to the file with s.strip() and s.replace(), it should work fine. You run the program from a directory that is different from where the music files reside.

Comment: Is it a typo or you have extra `space` in song title `' Toto - Africa.mp3'`?

Comment: don't remove path. After removing path player doesn't open files from folder `/home/pi/Desktop/Muziek/` but probably from `/home/pi/Desktop/`

Comment: @Mike Bessonov yeah but when I display the song name you will see the full path aswell..

Comment: Boris it isn't a typo, i the code makes that space and i think that that is the problem but I dont know how to fix it...

Comment: @user2682863 it exist It worked in previous versions

Answer (score 0):

I used os.listdir('') instead of glob.